# Ubuntu printing problem

Tags: printing, 20.04

I own a Brother DCP-7060D printer. I am struggling with a problem right now. The printer is connected to a Raspberry Pi 1B and shared via CUPS. Windows clients have no problems, the printer works perfectly fine. However I have a PC with Ubuntu 20.04. No matter which protocol I use the printing does not work. The printer has been added by itself and it does not work. I tried IPP smb and http protocols and it still does not print anything. I have no other printer to check whether cups is working properly or not.
Do you have any ideas how to solve this issue?
Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the linux driver on the Ubuntu client (not on the Raspberry)... see here:

https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=dcp7060d_all

Comment: I have done it and I am using this driver. Still no luck

Comment: You mean that you have installed the driver and then (and only then) installed the printer from the system configuration? If you do not do that, and in that order, I am sorry, it won't work...